# How to handle multiple templates (html/css) in angular2?

Tags: html, css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

We are building a web-app with Angular2. We need to have multiple templates (html and css) for each component but with the same behavior.

We know before build what template to use. So we would like to build (or serve for development) with "template1" or "template2" => different layouts for one component. We don't want to include in bundles every template but only one.

At the end we would like to be able to build with this kind of script:

```
npm run build template1
```

We are thinking of this folder organisation:

```
-src
   -app
      -component
        - temlate.1.html
        - temlate.2.html
        - style.1.scss
        - style.2.scss
        - main.scss
        - component.ts
```

How could we do it? In webpack ?

---

I have tried this way with a global variable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
const myGlobal = require('../globals');
const template = require('./templates/'+myGlobal.templateName+'/view1.component.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view1',
  template: template,
  styles: [require('./templates/'+myGlobal.templateName+'/view1.component.scss')]
})
```

It is working fine on "ng serve" "ng build" but not "ng build -prod"

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'require', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol View1Component in D:/git_/ngCustomTpl2/
src/app/view1/view1.component.ts, resolving symbol View1Component in D:/git_/ngCustomTpl2/src/app/view1/view1.component.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\git_\ngCustomTpl2\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: Did you check with `ng-show` instead of 2 different templates.

Comment: It could be an option or ng-switch. But if we can seperate in the build app, that would be better.

Comment: Your mindset is wrong here. You should look at a component's template and code as one entity. Template is not something you should wrap in and out, it's something that's supposed to produce a different layout depending on some configuration variables you give it.

Comment: We have to work on 4 templating, that's a lot of css and html which would be bundle for nothing with *ngIf, don't you think?